# My Loop is not working - it exits before it should

Tags: c#, loops

I'm new to programming. I tried this code and the loop is not working. The console application just ends after one operation, and I would like to continue doing more until I choose to say "no." Where am I making a mistake here? I want the program to keep going until I say so. Thanks in advance.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Program to convert USA Dollars to five different currencies,");
        Console.WriteLine();
        double dollars, euros, turkisLira, yen, britishPounds, mexicanPeso;
        char option;
        euros = 0.72;
        turkisLira = 2.09;
        yen = 101.73;
        britishPounds = 0.59;
        mexicanPeso = 13.03;

        string answer = "Y";

        do
        {

            Console.Write("Enter the Amount of USA Dollars to Convert:");
            dollars = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("1.Convert to Euros");
            Console.WriteLine("2.Convert to Turkis Lira");
            Console.WriteLine("3.Convert to Japanes Yen");
            Console.WriteLine("4.Convert to British Pounds");
            Console.WriteLine("5.Convert to Mexican Pesos");
            Console.Write("Enter the option of Currency you wish to convert : ");

            option = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (option)
            {
                case '1':
                    euros = dollars * euros;
                    Console.WriteLine("The amount of Euros given is : {0}", euros);
                    break;
                case '2':
                    turkisLira = dollars * turkisLira;
                    Console.WriteLine("The amount of Turkis Liras given is : {0}", turkisLira);
                    break;
                case '3':
                    yen = dollars * yen;
                    Console.WriteLine("The amount of Japanes Yen given is : {0}", yen);
                    break;
                case '4':
                    britishPounds = dollars * britishPounds;
                    Console.WriteLine("The amount of British Pounds given is : {0}", britishPounds);
                    break;
                case '5':
                    mexicanPeso = dollars * mexicanPeso;
                    Console.WriteLine("The amount of Mexican Pesos given is : {0}", mexicanPeso);
                    break;

            }
            Console.WriteLine(" Do you wish to do more conversions? (yes/no)");
            answer = Console.ReadLine();

            if (answer.Equals("Y"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yes");
            }
            else if (answer.Equals("N"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No");
            }
        } while (answer.ToLower() == "y'");
```

Comment: Any answer excpet "y" would cause the loop to end. Is that intended?

Comment: The only issue I see is that you have a ' (apostrophy) in the while test, should be `answer.ToLower() == "y"` not `answer.ToLower() == "y'"`

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is

> I will like to continue doing more until I choose to say No

while your exist condition is

```
(answer.ToLower() == "y'");
```

So, if somebody clicks anything other than y, the loop would exit. You would want the exist condition to be

```
(answer.ToLower() != "n'");-
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have miss type ' in "y'" where you just want receive "y" to continue.